# Loading Indicator on Web View

Tags: ios, uiwebview, activity-indicator

My app shows articles from an RSS feed in a table view then when you select a row, opens a web view controller to show the article.  I'm trying to add a loading indicator.  If I select a row, the indicator will show briefly and then disappear before the page is fully loaded.  Also, if I go back to the table view and select a different row, the loading indicator never shows up. I'm using a custom loading indicator called SVProgressHUD and it works fine elsewhere in the app.  I don't think that is the problem though.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in my table view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[webViewController webView]loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];

    // Grab the selected item
    RSSItem *entry = [[channel items]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    // Construct a URL with the link string of the item
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[entry link]];

    // Construct a request object with that URL
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Load the request into the web view
    [[webViewController webView]loadRequest:req];
    webViewController.hackyURL = url;
}
```

The loading indicator is started on this line in viewDidLoad of the WebViewController:

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];
```

And here is my WebViewController.

```
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "TUSafariActivity.h"
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"

@implementation WebViewController
@synthesize webView=webView, hackyURL=hackyURL;

- (void)loadView
{
    // Create an instance of UIWebView as large as the screen
    CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame];
    UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:screenFrame];
    webView = wv;
    NSLog(@"%@",webView.request.URL);
    // Tell web view to scale web content to fit within bounds of webview
    [wv setScalesPageToFit:YES];

    [self setView:wv];
}

- (UIWebView *)webView
{ 
    return (UIWebView *)[self view];
}

- (void) showMenu
{
    NSURL *urlToShare = hackyURL;
    NSArray *activityItems = @[urlToShare];
    TUSafariActivity *activity = [[TUSafariActivity alloc] init];

    __block UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:@[activity]];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:^{activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = nil; activityVC = nil;}];
}

- (void)toggleBars:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    BOOL barsHidden = self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden;

    if (!barsHidden)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
        [self hideTabBar:self.tabBarController];
    }
    else if (barsHidden)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
        [self showTabBar:self.tabBarController];
    }

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!barsHidden animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];

    UIBarButtonItem *systemAction = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(showMenu)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = systemAction;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleBars:)];
    [webView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    singleTap.delegate = self;

    // self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    float fHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    if(  UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) )
    {
        fHeight = screenRect.size.width;
    }

    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, fHeight, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        }
        else
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, fHeight)];
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void) showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    float fHeight = screenRect.size.height - 49.0;

    if(  UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) )
    {
        fHeight = screenRect.size.width - 49.0;
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, fHeight, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        }
        else
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, fHeight)];
        }
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //stop the activity indicator when done loading
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 12):

You should use the `delegate` functions of a `webview` see below

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
   //SHOW HUD
}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
  //KILL HUD
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    if(!webView.loading){
         //KILL HUD
    }
}
```

In `webview` normally caching happens, so HUD might not show for long as it will show for the first load.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I tried implementing those methods with a UIActivityIndicatorView and it shows up but I can't get it to stop and disappear when the page is done loading.

Comment: I placed break points at those methods and it looks like they aren't even getting called.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed.  I just had to add

```
webView.delegate = self;
```