# How to keep showing splash screen until webview is finished loading. objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, splash-screen

After my splash screen loads there is white background for a few seconds until the html loads. How can I keep displaying the splash screen till the webivew loads.

Comment: Use `UIWebView Delegates` to show and hide the SplashImage in your ViewController. `– webViewDidFinishLoad:` and `– webViewDidStartLoad:`

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216806/loading-indicator-on-web-view/18217084#18217084

Answer (score 1):

You can add an UIIMageView with the splash screen image over the UIWebView 
Of course the view controller showing both views must be the UIWebView delegate and when it receives

```
– webViewDidFinishLoad:
```

or

```
– webView:didFailLoadWithError:
```

in case of error of course you should remove the image view

Answer (score 0):

Implement the [`UIWebViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods.

```
//When webview starts loading
– webViewDidStartLoad:
//When webview finish loading 
– webViewDidFinishLoad:
//Error occured when loading webview
– webView:didFailLoadWithError:
```

You will need to create a custom splash screen as you cannot control the system splash screen. It can be a `UIViewController` with `UImageView` which displays the same `Default.png` image. Just set this view controller on the `window` once `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` gets called. Refer [this tutorial](http://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/iphone-dev-how-to-implement-a-splash-screen/) for creating custom splash screen.

Remove the splash screen from window only when `webViewDidFinishLoad` or `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` gets called.

Hope that helps!